# remote desktop virtualization host cannot be installed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I just installed a fresh copy of windows server 2012 r2, then i went to install a ADDC and set a forest name then followed the wizard, after that i tried to install remote desktop virtual machine, i chose my only server which im working on for RD connection broker, Virtualization host and gateway. after installation finished i got a reboot then before login screen i get "cannot complete the configurations, undoing the configurations then another restart and when i got back to windows server manager i found these errors in remote desktop log:

```
Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed to redirect the user XXXX\Administrator. 
Error: NULL
```

and

```
The Remote Desktop Connection Broker server could not enumerate the targets for the provider named NULL from the database.

Pooled virtual desktop collection name: NULL
Error: Logon to the database failed.
```

also these warnings:

```
Remote Desktop Services failed to join the Connection Broker on server SERVER.mydomain.net.
```

is there any configuration im missing?

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried to setup a terminal services feature on a domain controller?  AFAIK that simply isn't supported.  Domain controllers should have any remote desktop services roles installed.

Comment: i tried to install remote desktop on domain controller, why it should not be supported?

Comment: Well the primary reason it isn't supported is because Microsoft says it isn't supported, and hasn't designed the software for it actually work.

Comment: so does it mean i should demote domain from this server and remove active directory then try to install remote virtual desktop?